# Invisible APNS Push Notifications

Tags: xcode, apple-push-notifications, push

I'm adding APNS push notifications to my app. I correctly registered all the certificates, I store correctly into a database all the device's tokens, and I'm also able to send notifications to them.

This is an example of the push notification I send:

```
$payload = '{
      "aps" :
        {
            "alert" : "' . $message .  '",
        "content-available" : 1,                     
            "badge" : 0,            
        },
      "data-id" : 11
    }';
```

This notification contains a variable called `data-id`. I'd like my app, before showing the notification, to check if the user would like to receive that specific notification with that data-id.

I found this method that could do what I'm looking for:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
```

The problem is that the notification is shown to the user before calling that method.
Is it possible send an "invisible" notification that users don't see, after which it calls the previous method that checks if the notify has to be shown or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove `alert` from your payload, then the notification will be invisible to the user.  You will be responsible for showing an alert / relevant information to the user after you've received it.

Comment: I left content-available=1 and removed alert and everything just worked fine. Thank you so much.